# Server refuses connection only sometimes only for a particular POST REQUEST Android?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httprequest, httpresponse

This is strange, I have an App that connects to the server and everything works as expected except when I try to make an AsyncTask with a POST REQUEST that recovers some data which I then use to paint a pie Chart on my Activity. It is strange because every time I first launch this Activity the device hangs up for a while and then either the App crashes or the AsyncTask is cancelled (making my activity blank without the pie chart beign painted) or (third option) the chart is painted as it should.

Now here is the LogCat warning:

```
03-22 09:24:47.974: W/System.err(1828): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://mydomain.biz refused
03-22 09:24:47.986: W/System.err(1828):     at        org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
```

It is a free no-ip domain with DynDNS mapped through my router to an Apache web server, and everithing works great sometimes (as I said before) and sometimes not (expecially when I first launch the activity).

It is strange because the server responds very quickly when I use the browser, so I guess it is not a server problem, and as I said only in this Activity were I make the request the device hangs up waiting before connection is refused. For the other Activities were I am making requests to the same script listener everything works great.

So what could be the problem and what can be a possible solution?

I also would like to ask why the app crashes for every request I tried to make if I make requests via "https://", I have it enabled (of course the certificate is not authenticated) on my server so it shouldn't make problem, should it?

Thanks for the attention! Hope for some help!

Comment: I am facing the same, please let me know if you find any solution

Comment: Hi I didn't resolve yet, hope for some elucidation on the topic, anyway, I'll let you know if I found something interesting!